# How to count how many times a value is true in an hour/day in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm coding an alarm app and want to count how many times the alarm has been triggered in an hour and in a day. I use redux toolkit to handle the state of the alarm (true/false) and the reducer `countAlarm` to increment the count. Right now `handleCount` dispatches `countAlarm` every time `alarmValue` is true. I would like to count how many times the `alarmValue` is true in an hour and in a day. How do I do that?

```
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
      const countValue = useSelector((state) => state.count.value);
      const alarmValue = useSelector((state) => state.alarm.active);

      const handleCount = () => {
        if (alarmValue) {
        dispatch(countAlarm());
      }}

      useEffect(() => {
        handleCount()
      }, [alarmValue])

      return (
        <View>
          <Text>{countValue}</Text>
        </View>

        ...
```

`countAlarm`:

```
    import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

    const initialStateValue = {
        value: 0
    }

    const countSlice = createSlice({
        name: 'count',
        initialState: initialStateValue,
        reducers: {
            countAlarm: (state = initialStateValue) => {
                state.value++;
            },
        }
    });

    export const {countAlarm} = countSlice.actions;
    export default countSlice.reducer;
```

`alarmValue`:

```
    import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

    const initialStateValue = {
        active: false,
    }

    const alarmSlice = createSlice({
        name: 'alarm',
        initialState: initialStateValue,
        reducers: {
            alarmOn: (state = initialStateValue) => {
                state.active = true;
            },
            alarmOff: (state = initialStateValue) => {
                state.active = false;
            },
        }
    });

    export const {alarmOn, alarmOff} = alarmSlice.actions;
    export default alarmSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: How many different actions can lead to `state.alarm.active` being true in the first place? Can you please share that piece of code?

Comment: Right now I activate/deactivate the alarm via a simulation button. It dispatches a reducer that changes the state, so only one action. In the future I will use a real device.

Comment: please share the code for that dispatch and reducer

Comment: I edited my original code

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by in an hour / in a day?
I would append the data:

```
const initialStateValue = {
        value: 0,
        numberOfAlarmsInDay: 0
        numberOfAlarmsPerHour: {
           perFirstHour: 0,
           perSecondHour: 0,
           ...
        }
    }
```

Then, you need

- either the time as a a PayloadAction or you read something like the system data in the reducer to determine which counter to set
- a trigger for a new day to reset the values, most likely as another action. If you want to do that in a reducer (with the first alarm of a new day), you need to keep the day to know when to reset again -> but the data may be dirty!

Hope this helpsyou a bit to advance further!

Comment: I have no idea how to do that but thank you very much for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

You should not really go this "roundabout through the component". Instead, let your `countSlice` just react to the `alamSlice`'s `alarmOn` action:

```js
    import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
    import { alarmOn } from './alarmSlice'

    const initialStateValue = {
        value: 0
    }

    const countSlice = createSlice({
        name: 'count',
        initialState: initialStateValue,
        reducers: {
          // reducers for "this slice"
        },
        extraReducers: builder => {
          // reducers for actions owned by other slices
          builder.addCase(alarmOn, (state) => { state.value++; })
        }
    });
```

See [allow many reducers to respond to the same action](https://redux.js.org/style-guide#allow-many-reducers-to-respond-to-the-same-action) in the Redux Style guide.

(Of course you could also just keep the `counter` in your `alarmSlice`; depending on the complexity that could also be a fine solution)

PS: don't do `(state = initialStateValue) => {` - you don't need to initialize your state like this, `createSlice` takes care of that.